# Horizontal lines in Xamarin Microcharts - line chart

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using microcharts on my Xamarin app. 
 
Is it possible to display chart like this:

[image]

Key thing is in horizontal lines. I want to display values on the left side like in the picture above, not on top of the cart like provided by default (picture below).

All I'm getting is:

[image]


EDIT 1:
Here's how I crated it:
xaml code:

```
<microcharts:ChartView
    x:Name="RpmChart">
</microcharts:ChartView>
```

Codebehind:

```
        RpmChart.Chart = new LineChart();
        RpmChart.Chart.Entries = context.EngineRPMChartEnteries;
```

Comment: we can't help you if you don't show us what you are doing

Comment: @Jason I just made an edit regarding your comment. Let me know if you need some more information :)

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  You have to show the relevant code if you expect us to help you.  The screenshots you added are not helpful.

Comment: @Jason Thank's on advice. I made a new edit, with the code.